# Calling WebServices Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a simple ajax request that I am trying to call a web service I created. The web service code is never being executed. I got this code sample from the net and I think maybe I am calling the url wrong in the jquery i dunno?

here is the jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 

    alert("Hi");
        $("#btnTitleQuery").bind("click", function() {
            $("#query_results").empty();
            $("#query_results").append('<table id="ResultsTable" class="BooksTable"><tr><th>BookNum</th><th>Title</th><th>Author</th></tr>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "BookServices.asmx/GetBooksByTitle",
                data: '{ strTitle: "' + $("#txtTitle").val() + '" }',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    var c = eval(msg.d);
                    for (var i in c) {
                        $("#ResultsTable tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + c[i][0] + "</td><td>" + c[i][1] + "</td><td>" + c[i][2] + "</td></tr>");
                    }
                }
            });
        })
        $("#btnAuthorQuery").bind("click", function() {
            $("#query_results").empty();
            $("#query_results").append('<table id="ResultsTable" class="BooksTable"><tr><th>BookNum</th><th>Title</th><th>Author</th></tr>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "BookServices.asmx/GetBooksByAuthor",
                data: '{ strAuthor: "' + $("#txtAuthor").val() + '" }',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    var c = eval(msg.d);
                    for (var i in c) {
                        $("#ResultsTable tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + c[i][0] + "</td><td>" + c[i][1] + "</td><td>" + c[i][2] + "</td></tr>");
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    }); 
</script>
```

The web service is in my root directory.

```
using System;

 using System.Web;

 using System.Collections;

 using System.Web.Services;

using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

 using System.Data;

  using System.Data.Odbc;

   using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

 using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace TryWillJSON
{

 [WebService(Description = "Web services to query the book database.", Namespace = "http://www.williamsportwebdeveloper.com/")]

  [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

   [ScriptService]

 public class BookServices : System.Web.Services.WebService {



       public BookServices () {



        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 

         //InitializeComponent(); 

     }



     [WebMethod(Description = "Gets the books matching part of a title.")]

    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

     public string GetBooksByTitle(string strTitle) {

        OdbcConnection objConnection = new OdbcConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Books"].ConnectionString);

         OdbcCommand objCommand = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM reading WHERE Title LIKE '%" + strTitle + "%' ORDER BY BookNum;", objConnection);

         DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();

         OdbcDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(objCommand);

         objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "reading");

           objConnection.Close();



         // Create a multidimensional jagged array

        string[][] JaggedArray = new string[objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count][];

        int i = 0;

         foreach (DataRow rs in objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)

        {

            JaggedArray[i] = new string[] { rs["BookNum"].ToString(), rs["Title"].ToString(), rs["Author"].ToString() };

             i = i + 1;

          }



        // Return JSON data

         JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

      string strJSON = js.Serialize(JaggedArray);

       return strJSON;

      }



     [WebMethod(Description = "Gets the books matching part of an author's name.")]

   [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

    public string GetBooksByAuthor(string strAuthor)

       {

         OdbcConnection objConnection = new OdbcConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Books"].ConnectionString);

         OdbcCommand objCommand = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM reading WHERE Author LIKE '%" + strAuthor + "%' ORDER BY BookNum;", objConnection);

         DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();

        OdbcDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(objCommand);

        objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "reading");

        objConnection.Close();



          // Create a multidimensional jagged array

         string[][] JaggedArray = new string[objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count][];

        int i = 0;

        foreach (DataRow rs in objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)

      {
             JaggedArray[i] = new string[] { rs["BookNum"].ToString(), rs["Title"].ToString(), rs["Author"].ToString() };

             i = i + 1;

        }



          // Return JSON data

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

         string strJSON = js.Serialize(JaggedArray);

         return strJSON;

     }



   }
}
```

I can see the alert hits, but in firebug when I check whats in the "msg" parameter of the jquery function firebug tells me this "ReferenceError: msg is not defined"

Here is where I am getting the code: 
williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=494

If anyone has time can you see if you can set it up correctly in visual studio

Here is a fiddle I setup as well for what its worth
http://jsfiddle.net/npl77/U33XS/

Comment: that is some horrific white space on the ASP.NET. Please tell me copying and pasting your code broke your whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameters do not have the proper single tick marks around the property names
Rewrite them to look like this:

```
data: "{ 'strAuthor': '" + $("#txtAuthor").val() + "' }",

data: "{ 'strTitle': '" + $("#txtTitle").val() + "' }",
```

because of this, your parameters are not matching up when being checked on the server-side. Therefore, your code is never executed. That is the first mistake I found ... there could be more,

check that then we'll see.

Also, you can use JSON natively in javascript which will make this tedious and error proned string building process hands off. You just need to get a copy of the small JSON library here and add it to your project (it's only a javascript file btw).

http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/

Here is an example

```
 //using native JSON
    var per = { FirstName: $('#fName').val(),
                LastName : $('#lName').val(),
                Address : $('#address').val(),
                City : $('#city').val(),
                State : $('#state').val(),
                ZipCode : $('#zip').val()
              };

   $.ajax(
   {
       type: "POST",
       url: "Default.aspx/GetPersonObj",
       data: JSON.stringify(per),  //<---- right here the magic happens
       contentType: "application/json; charset=uft-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (rsp) { SetPerson(rsp); },
       error: function (rsp)
       {
           alert(rsp.responseText); //<--- this is always good to add, that way you can get some feedback from the ajax call about what the hell went wrong.
       }
   });
```

Comment: @Matt I can see the input data is being populated correctly also I am fairly sure now the url is correct but still not firing. If you have time can you see if you can get it setup correctly in visual studio I am getting this code from here: http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=494

Comment: @Nick LaMarca When you say "see the input data is being populated correctly" are you just stating that you did an alert() on the string after making it? Bc you are absolutely required to have tick marks AROUND the property name as well as the string value. And your code does not indicate that you do.

Comment: @Matt I changed it to your structure, but still am not hitting the service.

Comment: @Matt 
Here is a fiddle I setup as well for what its worth
http://jsfiddle.net/npl77/U33XS/

Comment: @Nick Ty for that. Add the error callback like the one in my example. This will report the error that you are having

Comment: @Matt adding the error handler. The alert box comes back as "Undefined") so rsp.responseText is undefined

Comment: @Nick Interesting. I would open up firebug assuming you have it or dev tools in IE and put a breakpoint on the alert line. Then examine the rsp obj in the watch window. From there you can look at its contents and sift through it till you find something that resembles error ouput. See what you find.

Comment: @Matt adding the error handler to the code at least made the web service breakpoint hit for whatever reason, so thanks. I think I have the sql connection wrong. It seems in the sample project the author has the db setup on his localhost and obviously I do not so the web service breaks there.

Answer (score 0):

What is the location of the file making the AJAX call? Maybe trying modifying your JQuery URL:

```
url: "/BookServices.asmx/GetBooksByTitle",
```

Comment: Root directory. I right clicked on the project name and added a new web service in visual studio

Comment: Are you trying to post data to your service in JSON format? By default, $ajax function serializes the data component as a query string, unless you set the processData option to "false".

Answer (score 0):

Try using Firefox/Firebug/Console or IE+Fiddler to see what is happening with that $.ajax() call.  You could also add an error handler to that $.ajax() call to capture the error event and spit out some info.

Is any request made?

You said "The web service code is never being executed.", so I am guessing you have a debugger attached to the VS.NET website, but since a breakpoint is not being hit, you need to determine what is happening client side first.

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the web service in visual studio and it never hits. Thats why I thought the url was wrong, but I think the url is correct. There must be something fundemental why the service isnt firing....If I use fiddle how is it gonna know where the web service is at?

Comment: Fiddler will show you the request that the browser makes from the $.ajax() call and then the response from the web server, which I am betting is an error page. Also see Matthew Cox's answer as well. Seems that you need some quotes around your data parameter names. That could be your only problem, but Fiddler will help you see the error messages that are being generated.

Comment: @Nick LaMarca You have purely syntactical error that needs to be addressed first before the method will be invoked. I suggest you examine the post I made.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that haven't been mentioned yet.

1) Are those buttons `<input type="submit" />` (which is what `asp:Button` renders by default)?  If so, you need to prevent their default action so that the page isn't reloaded at the same time that your AJAX request is beginning.

If the buttons are triggering submits, you should prevent the default action near the top of your event handler, like this:

```
$("#btnTitleQuery").bind("click", function(evt) {
  // This prevents the form submission.
  evt.preventDefault();

  // Your $.ajax() and rendering code here.
});
```

2) You shouldn't manually serialize the service method's return value and deserialize it on the client-side.  There's already one layer of JSON serialization happening.  Instead of returning type string from those methods, go with something like this:

```
public class Book
{
  public string BookNum { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Author { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod(Description = "Gets the books matching part of a title.")]
public List<Book> GetBooksByTitle(string strTitle) {

  OdbcConnection objConnection = new OdbcConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Books"].ConnectionString);

  // Be careful.  You've got a SQL injection vulnerability here.
  OdbcCommand objCommand = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM reading WHERE Title LIKE '%" + strTitle + "%' ORDER BY BookNum;", objConnection);

  DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  OdbcDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(objCommand);

  objDataAdapter.Fill(dt);

  objConnection.Close();

  List<Book> result = new List<Book>();

  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {
    result.Add(new Book() {
      BookNum = row["BookNum"].ToString(),
      Title = row["Title"].ToString(),
      Author = row["Author"].ToString()
    });
  }

  return result;
}
```

Then, you could consume that by changing your `$.ajax()` call like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "BookServices.asmx/GetBooksByTitle",
  data: '{ strTitle: "' + $("#txtTitle").val() + '" }',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    for(var i = 0; i < msg.d.length; i++) {
      // You should avoid accessing the DOM during every loop.
      $("#ResultsTable tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + msg.d[i].BookNum + "</td><td>" + msg.d[i].Title + "</td><td>" + msg.d[i].Author + "</td></tr>");
    }
  }
});
```

3) Finally, this would be a great place to use jQuery Templates instead of all the string concatenation.  You could use a simple template like this:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="BooksQueryTemplate">
  <table id="ResultsTable" class="BooksTable">
    <tr>
      <th>BookNum</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Author</th></tr>
    </tr>
    {{each d}}
    <tr>
      <td>${BookNum}</td>
      <td>${Title}</td>
      <td>${Author}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
</script>
```

Then, render it in your $.ajax() call like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "BookServices.asmx/GetBooksByTitle",
  data: '{ strTitle: "' + $("#txtTitle").val() + '" }',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    $('#BooksQueryTemplate').tmpl(msg).appendTo('#query_results');
  }
});
```